# C++ Shared Library - Expose Methods - JAVA

Tags: java, c++, shared-libraries

I have a C++ Shared Library with many headers and methods. Also I have one .cpp file which controls the whole library. I mean it just calls only one method, then inside this method another is called , then inside the another other methods are called etc etc. My question is: If I want to use this lib with Java for example should I expose and wrap only the top level method (the first called) or I should expose and wrap each method called from this method?

Comment: Only expose what you need to. Note: consider using JNA.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I am going to use JNA. But for me it is still not clear what I need to expose. Basically one method is enough for me, but this method calls other methods inside. Should I expose them too? That is my question. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, if you are sure your Java side won't need them, why would you expose them? Or did I completely misunderstand the question?

Comment: Yes sorry. Maybe bad wording from me.In Java I want to call again only one method (but this method inside calls other methods). Is it my responsibly to handle them?